Postman always shows econnrefused 127.0.0.1:8083
Whatever I do I am getting only econn refused error in postman. Sometimes it shows a 401 unauthorized error. The browser asks for a login at http://localhost:8083/projectonethree. Mostly it is econnrefused error.
I have only a simple code. I have deleted all lines except a return "successful" line
I didnt find resources for plain econnrefused error where it is hard to find the error.
I was able to successfully use itext in a java program in eclipse. But, I'm experiencing only econn refused in all my spring projects. I have copied my main class and controller class to show its simple code only.
The annotations are all correct without errors.
My main class
package com.rejolaprojectonethree.testonethree;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestonethreeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestonethreeApplication.class, args);


    
    }

}


My simple controller class



package com.rejolaprojectonethree.testonethree;

import java.io.Console;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {
    
    @GetMapping("/projectonethree")
    public String home() {
        return "successful";
    }
}

Common omitted frames error. I get 24 common omitted frames error even with only one return statement line of code. Code has previously run even with 85 common omitted frames error. But, this time it is not running with even 24 errors. Copy paste wasnt neat. Sorry for the jagged text in the spring console code.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v2.5.4)[0;39m

[2m2024-10-04 16:56:15.585[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6064[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.r.t.TestonethreeApplication           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting TestonethreeApplication using Java 22.0.1 on Venkylappy with PID 6064 (C:\Users\Venkatesh\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.22.1.RELEASE\testonethree\target\classes started by Venkatesh in C:\Users\Venkatesh\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.22.1.RELEASE\testonethree)
[2m2024-10-04 16:56:15.589[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6064[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.r.t.TestonethreeApplication           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2024-10-04 16:56:15.940[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m6064[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\Venkatesh\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.22.1.RELEASE\testonethree\target\classes\com\rejolaprojectonethree\testonethree\HomeController.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\Venkatesh\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.22.1.RELEASE\testonethree\target\classes\com\rejolaprojectonethree\testonethree\HomeController.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 66
[2m2024-10-04 16:56:15.988[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m6064[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\Venkatesh\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.22.1.RELEASE\testonethree\target\classes\com\rejolaprojectonethree\testonethree\HomeController.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\Venkatesh\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.22.1.RELEASE\testonethree\target\classes\com\rejolaprojectonethree\testonethree\HomeController.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 66
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:452) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:315) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:132) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:296) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.rejolaprojectonethree.testonethree.TestonethreeApplication.main(TestonethreeApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\Venkatesh\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.22.1.RELEASE\testonethree\target\classes\com\rejolaprojectonethree\testonethree\HomeController.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 66
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:60) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:429) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 66
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:199) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:287) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:57) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 24 common frames omitted


All help is appreciated. I am new to spring, dont hesitate to write answers in detail.

Thank you

Run a spring program.
Only econnrefused in postman
I got it to run only once with system generated password and java 17.
It now shows 46 common frames omitted. Postman econnrefused
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v3.3.4)[0;39m

[2m2024-10-07T14:34:36.007+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9316[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[testtwotwo] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mc.p.testtwotwo.TesttwotwoApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting TesttwotwoApplication using Java 17.0.11 with PID 9316 (C:\Users\Venkatesh\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.22.1.RELEASE\testtwotwo\target\classes started by Venkatesh in C:\Users\Venkatesh\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.22.1.RELEASE\testtwotwo)
[2m2024-10-07T14:34:36.012+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9316[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[testtwotwo] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mc.p.testtwotwo.TesttwotwoApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2024-10-07T14:34:36.823+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9316[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[testtwotwo] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2024-10-07T14:34:36.850+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9316[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[testtwotwo] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 15 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2024-10-07T14:34:36.917+05:30[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m9316[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[testtwotwo] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$SecurityFilterChainConfiguration
[2m2024-10-07T14:34:36.933+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9316[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[testtwotwo] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2024-10-07T14:34:36.965+05:30[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m9316[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[testtwotwo] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$SecurityFilterChainConfiguration
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:470) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:131) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:429) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:789) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:607) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at com.projtwotwo.testtwotwo.TesttwotwoApplication.main(TesttwotwoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@21588809]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:750) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:749) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:682) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:653) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:247) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:240) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:183) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:158) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberOutcomes.getConditionOutcome(AbstractNestedCondition.java:195) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberOutcomes.<init>(AbstractNestedCondition.java:189) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberConditions.lambda$getMatchOutcomes$0(AbstractNestedCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.MultiValueMapAdapter.forEach(MultiValueMapAdapter.java:179) ~[spring-core-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1553) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberConditions.getMatchOutcomes(AbstractNestedCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberMatchOutcomes.<init>(AbstractNestedCondition.java:78) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition.getMatchOutcome(AbstractNestedCondition.java:63) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.4.jar:3.3.4]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
    ... 46 common frames omitted

Src/main/java in another project was accidentally deleted. I dont know how. I had to update maven project to get the output. Now it works fine after update. I still have to use password from 'Using generated security password: 'from spring console in postman authorization to get output. Please help me set password for authorization in postman.
Tks to the great community that got me working without days of headache.

Thanks for the quick response
I tried changing to jdk 20 and jdk 21 in run configurations. I am getting 80 common omitted frames error.
I am not able to change to jdk 20 or below. The run button is greyed out
Jdk greyed out

I changed to java 17 in spring initializr and it now shows no errror. Tks. But still localhost is asking for username password. SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mypass'); does not work. Nor does alter user and other commands dont work. Alas, postman again changes btw localhost username password and econnrefused

postman again changes btw 401 unauthorized and econnrefused. Browser asks username password or shows unable to connect

Program now works with username 'user' and 'Using generated security password: 'from spring console. How do I get spring generated password every time I run? Will spring-boot-starter-security generate password everytime? I cant change this password also. Can you help me change basic auth password in postman? SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mypass'); does not work. Nor does alter user and other commands dont work. ALTER is not recognized as a command. I'm in mysql bin folder in cmd. Tks for all the help

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It is probably because of a compatibility issue due to the JDK/JRE installed on your system
The error from your log:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 66
From the app log, I can see that you are using Spring boot 2.5.4 and Java 22. Please try downgrading the Java version, maybe to Java 21 or Java 19, and then check.
